# load image in web view from a .html file

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

How can I load an image in iphone webview from a .html file?

Comment: Doesn't the img-element work like in normal HTML?

Comment: at safari working but not in webview, i wana ur help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *bundleBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: bundlePath];

    NSLog(@"webview %@", bundlePath);


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];  
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    NSString * html =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
    if (htmlData) {  
       [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:bundleBaseURL];  
    }
```

Now in your html you can simply refer to the image as

Comment: Awesome can you now accept my answer as and or vote it up. Don't want to miss out on points. Cheers. John.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `UIWebView` has two methods: `-loadHtmlString:baseURL:` and `-loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`

You can get the file data using NSData's `-initWithContentsOfFile:`, then pass it to the latter of those methods above.

EDIT: Whoops, I didn't notice the img part. But it still should work. Are you trying to load *only* the image?

Comment: my images are stored in recourse / images directory, can u send me complete code, me working at this from last 2 days but....?
plz...

Comment: i m trying .html page, in this table, text, and images. but image is't be loaded.

Comment: i m trying to develop an ebook,