# How to add an image as html and load it to webview in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I am implementing a webview based application, in that I tried to load an image but it is not coming as expected. I don't know what is the problem. The following is my code that I tried. Please suggest me if I did any thing wrong.

```
  NSString *returnString = @"";

returnString = [returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<html><body>" withString:@"<body> <p>Hello Sekhar"];
returnString = [returnString stringByAppendingString:@"<img src='tutorial/images/bg1.png'"];   
returnString = [returnString stringByAppendingString:@"alt='footer'"];
returnString = [returnString stringByAppendingString:@"align='middle' width='140' height='32' />"];
returnString = [returnString stringByAppendingString:@"</p></body></html>"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:returnString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:www.google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *bundleBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: bundlePath];

    NSLog(@"webview %@", bundlePath);


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];  
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    NSString * html =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
    if (htmlData) {  
       [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:bundleBaseURL];  
    }
```

used the search function once: [load-image-in-web-view-from-a-html-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186883/load-image-in-web-view-from-a-html-file)